# How to update the azimuth with the rotation matrix from gyroscope?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-orientation, gyroscope

Suppose I have my current orientation as `(azimuth, pitch, roll)`. Now I wish to update my orientation with the gyroscope. According to the codes given by [the Android development web](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-gyro), I can obtain the so-called `deltaRotationMatrix` as follows:

```
// Create a constant to convert nanoseconds to seconds.
private static final float NS2S = 1.0f / 1000000000.0f;
private final float[] deltaRotationVector = new float[4]();
private float timestamp;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  // This timestep's delta rotation to be multiplied by the current rotation
  // after computing it from the gyro sample data.
  if (timestamp != 0) {
    final float dT = (event.timestamp - timestamp) * NS2S;
    // Axis of the rotation sample, not normalized yet.
    float axisX = event.values[0];
    float axisY = event.values[1];
    float axisZ = event.values[2];

    // Calculate the angular speed of the sample
    float omegaMagnitude = sqrt(axisX*axisX + axisY*axisY + axisZ*axisZ);

    // Normalize the rotation vector if it's big enough to get the axis
    // (that is, EPSILON should represent your maximum allowable margin of error)
    if (omegaMagnitude > EPSILON) {
      axisX /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisY /= omegaMagnitude;
      axisZ /= omegaMagnitude;
    }

    // Integrate around this axis with the angular speed by the timestep
    // in order to get a delta rotation from this sample over the timestep
    // We will convert this axis-angle representation of the delta rotation
    // into a quaternion before turning it into the rotation matrix.
    float thetaOverTwo = omegaMagnitude * dT / 2.0f;
    float sinThetaOverTwo = sin(thetaOverTwo);
    float cosThetaOverTwo = cos(thetaOverTwo);
    deltaRotationVector[0] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisX;
    deltaRotationVector[1] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisY;
    deltaRotationVector[2] = sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ;
    deltaRotationVector[3] = cosThetaOverTwo;
  }
  timestamp = event.timestamp;
  float[] deltaRotationMatrix = new float[9];
  SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(deltaRotationMatrix, deltaRotationVector);
    // User code should concatenate the delta rotation we computed with the current rotation
    // in order to get the updated rotation.
    // rotationCurrent = rotationCurrent * deltaRotationMatrix;
   }
}
```

**How should I proceed with this snippet so as to update my orientation?**

Comment: I see you picked the quaternion based representation. Sorry, I can't help you with that, I would have to derive the formulas first. In any case, I would start with [this document](http://sharenet-wii-motion-trac.googlecode.com/files/An_efficient_orientation_filter_for_inertial_and_inertialmagnetic_sensor_arrays.pdf).

Comment: @Ali  No it does not have to be the quaternion stuff. The core of my problem is that the gyroscope readings reported are the rotation rates around the phone's xyz coordinate system. But the azimuth is w.r.t. the world ENU coordinate system, I don't know what to do...

Comment: @Ali I don't even need any sort of complicated fusion. I only wish to add the related part of the rotation to the azimuth. because they are in different coordinates, I don;t know what to do.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you don't need a sophisticated sensor fusion. I just wanted to say that I don't know the update formulas for the quaternion form but I believe they can be derived from that document I linked to in my first comment. I have already given you a link to [a tutorial](http://gentlenav.googlecode.com/files/DCMDraft2.pdf) how to do it with the rotation matrix representation (which is much easier in my opinion).

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to multiply the deltaRotationMatrix by the rotationCurrentMatrix and then make a call to SensorManager.getOrientation(). You will need to implement a matrix multiplication method. You will also need an initial currentRotationMatrix, you can use the acceleration sensor and magnetic sensor with SensorManager.getRotationMatrix and SensorManager.getOrientation to get the initial currentRotationMatrix. Alternatively, you could use TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR to get the initial currentRotationMatrix.

```
    currentRotationMatrix = matrixMultiplication(
                currentRotationMatrix,
                deltaRotationMatrix);

    SensorManager.getOrientation(currentRotationMatrix,
                gyroscopeOrientation;
```

Unfortunately, what you will realize is that even the TYPE_GYROSCOPE sensor which is supposed to be calibrated for drift doesn't do a very good job and the sensor quickly drifts out of rotation with the device. Frustrating.

I have a GitHub repo with all of this implemented [here](https://github.com/BokiSoft/GyroscopeExplorer)
And a working project on the Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kircherelectronics.com.gyroscopeexplorer&hl=en)